# Printing in style in C

Tags: c, design-patterns, printing, numbers, output

How to get the following output in C:

```
1    2    3    2    1
4    5    6    5    4
7    8    9    8    7
10   11   12   11   10
13   14   15   14   13
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts?

Comment: What are your limitations on this assignment? I'm guessing a long `printf` chain wasn't what you had in mind. If you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf` with a format argument of `%-5d`. Character by character, it means:

- `%`: Introduce a format specifier rather than literal text.
- `-`: Left-align.
- `5`: Pad to 5 columns.
- `d`: Print an integer in base 10 (**d**ecimal)

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what your code is.

maybe you wanted to just do

```
printf("1 2 3 2 1\n 4 5 6 5 4\n7 8 9 8 7\n10 11 12 11 10\n13 14 15 14 13\n")
```

but here is another way

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int a;
    for(int f = 0; f < 4; f++)
    {
        for(a = x; a < x + 2; a++)
            printf("%d ", a);
        x = a;
        for(int a = x; a > x - 3; a--)
            printf("%d ", a);
        printf("\n");
        x++;
    }
}
```